# Mongo cannot write to primary

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have 3 node mongo with 1 primary and 2 secondary. One of my secondary node is down but the primary and the other secondary node is still up. The problem is now i cannot write to the primary. what is the reason as primary is still up but read operations are working. I am using connection string like

"mongodb://custom-pvc-mongodb-0.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017/admin"

the below is my rs.status()

```
{
    "set" : "custom-pvc-mongodb",
    "date" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:12.543Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(3),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 2,
    "votingMembersCount" : 3,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 3,
    "optimes" : {
            "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1670301216, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:36.252Z"),
            "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1670301216, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "appliedOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1670414650, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "durableOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1670414650, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:10.025Z"),
            "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:10.025Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1670301216, 1),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
            "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
            "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2022-11-25T07:35:27.387Z"),
            "electionTerm" : NumberLong(3),
            "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                    "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1669361650, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "numVotesNeeded" : 2,
            "priorityAtElection" : 1,
            "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
            "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
            "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2022-11-25T07:35:27.410Z"),
            "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2022-11-25T07:35:28.101Z")
    },
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "custom-pvc-mongodb-0.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 1052969,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1670414650, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(3)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:10Z"),
                    "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:10.025Z"),
                    "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:10.025Z"),
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1669361727, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2022-11-25T07:35:27Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 1,
                    "configTerm" : 3,
                    "self" : true,
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "custom-pvc-mongodb-1.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                    "health" : 0,
                    "state" : 8,
                    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                    "uptime" : 0,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:36.252Z"),
                    "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:36.252Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:11.496Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:41.424Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Error connecting to custom-pvc-mongodb-1.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017 :: caused by :: Could not find address for custom-pvc-mongodb-1.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative)",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : 1,
                    "configTerm" : 3
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "custom-pvc-mongodb-2.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 1052905,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1670301216, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(3)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1670301216, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(3)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:36Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:36Z"),
                    "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:36.252Z"),
                    "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2022-12-06T04:33:36.252Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2022-12-07T12:04:12.099Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2022-12-06T17:34:23.114Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : 1,
                    "configTerm" : 3
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1670414650, 1),
            "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"kmVIlznkue1ffD6Se8Ztbzc22j0="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong("7169853219500195844")
            }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1670414650, 1)
```

}

Comment: How do you connect? What is the connection string?

Comment: What is the error? What version are you using?

Comment: Also you could have some custom writeConcern like: w: 3 that will require acknowledgment from PRIMARY + both SECONDARY's , or maybe your live SECONDARY has votes:0 and your PRIMARY switched to SECONDARY and not able to receive writes ?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit added my connection string and rs.status() output in the question.

Comment: I am a bit concerned about `syncSourceHost : "", syncSourceId : -1` of member 2, it means it is not synchronized. Should be `syncSourceHost : "custom-pvc-mongodb-0.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local", syncSourceId : 0` Do you see any warnings in logfile of member 2?

Comment: Which version do you use? Do you use TLS/SSL?

Comment: @R2D2 `votes: 0` is not the case. rs.status() says `votingMembersCount: 3`, i.e. the ReplicaSet has 3 voting members.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Indeed it looks more like the available SECONDARY not synced , maybe output from rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()  can throw some light?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to entire ReplicaSet, not to a single node. Connection string would be this:

```
mongodb://custom-pvc-mongodb-0.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017,custom-pvc-mongodb-1.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017,custom-pvc-mongodb-2.custom-pvc-mongodb-svc.mongo-3033.svc.cluster.local:27017/admin?replicaSet=custom-pvc-mongodb
```

At connection it will automatically connect to the PRIMARY member. Switchover to new PRIMARY should be done automatically. You may add `&readPreference=primaryPreferred`

Comment: This connections str is fine. But In my connection str too I have mentioned the primary node only and it is still up. Only one of the secondary node is down. So ideally it should work as primary is up right?